# CentOS cronjobs location

Tags: centos, cron

I can't seem to find clear instructions on how crontab works on CentOS. When I (as root) edit my crontab using: `crontab -e` I see a list of cronjobs. However, when I edit /etc/crontab, nothing is listed there.

What is the difference?

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/where-is-the-crontab-file/

Answer (score 12):

All cron files for all users are located at /var/spool/cron. Each user has its own file. Although, editing those files manually will work - its recommended that you will use 'crontab -e' to edit those.

Comment: where are the user files specifically? I don't have permission to access that directory.